# "This field is required" POSTing to Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to POST to my django rest framework serializer using httpie and the following syntax:

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/traffic/geofences/ 
{
"id":13, 
"radius":40, 
"lat":0, 
"long":0, 
"name":"B"
}
```

The following error is returned:

```
{
"id":["This field is required."],
"name":["This field is required."],
"lat":["This field is required."],
"long":["This field is required."],
"radius":["This field is required."]
}
```

I don't understand why these fields are not accepted. What should the format look like? The server will be sent data from a mobile device and inserting it into the database via django rest framework.
Here is my Serializer and Model and View

Serializer:

```
class GeofenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
name = serializers.CharField()
lat = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, coerce_to_string=False)
long = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=6, coerce_to_string=False)
radius = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
class Meta:
    model = Geofence
    fields = ('id', 'name','lat', 'long', 'radius')

def create(self, valid_data):
    return Geofence.objects.create(**valid_data)
```

Model:

```
class Geofence(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Geofence", blank=False)
lat = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=6, max_digits=10, blank=False)
long = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=6, max_digits=10, blank=False)
radius = models.IntegerField(default=10, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "Geofence: " + str(self.name);
```

View:

```
class GeofencesView(APIView):
model = Geofence
serializer_class = GeofenceSerializer

def getId(self):
    return uuid.uuid4().int & (1<<64)-1

def get(self, request):
    fences = Geofence.objects.all()
    serializer = GeofenceSerializer(fences, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = GeofenceSerializer(data= request.data)
    serializer.id = -1
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

I have read the django rest framework documentation and the django docs. The get request works fine. If nothing else, I would appreciate someone pointing me to where this is discussed in  either documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're using the correct json format for httpie.

Try this instead:

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/traffic/geofences/ \
    id:=13 radius:=40 lat:=0 long:=0 name="B"
```